# Application crashes while trying to upload a pic to server

Tags: android, exception, server, upload

1.while I'm trying to upload a picture to server It works for some pictures but not for others , and when it crashes it shows the following error :

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
                  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
                  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
                  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
                  at com.example.th3hokage.pfev1.UploadPic.getPath(UploadPic.java:141)
                  at com.example.th3hokage.pfev1.UploadPic.uploadMultipart(UploadPic.java:81)
                  at com.example.th3hokage.pfev1.UploadPic.onClick(UploadPic.java:188)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6199)
                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11090)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23647)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

2.here is the methods that do the work I think that gonna be something about the cursor but I still don't know why I can upload some pictures and others not

```
 public void uploadMultipart() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    final String name2=pref.getString("name",null);
    //getting name for the image
    String name1 = editText.getText().toString().trim();
    String name=name1+name2;

    //getting the actual path of the image
    String path = getPath(filePath);

    //Uploading code
    try {
        String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        //Creating a multi part request
        new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                .addParameter("name", name) //Adding text parameter to the request
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(2)
                .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String path="";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: add cursor.moveToFirst(); after checking null condition

Comment: I did it but nothing changes :/

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor pointer is moved to another location. You need to change following,

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
```

to

```
if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
...
}
```

So you need to remove `cursor.moveToFirst();` before if condition.

Comment: I tried your update but it still shows the same exception

Comment: @C.yasser, try cleaning the project, it should work.

Comment: I've just clean it and nothing changes :/

Comment: The path of the picture chosen

Comment: if you print its value on console, then is it showing or not ? because, your error log says that you have `Index 0 requested, with a size of 0` meaning there is not such file

Comment: The problem is when I chose a picture from another directory all work fine but when I chose it from a specific directory where I stock picture that I take with my App it crashes